# Pictures turn out darker when going from RAW to JPG

Tags: post-processing, sony-alpha, capture-one

When I postprocess pictures in Capture One and do the final step and exporting to JPG, the JPG turns out a little darker than the RAW file I'm viewing in Capture One.

Does anyone have any idea of what could be the cause of this? Is it the color profile?

I'm using a Sony A7S if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the solution below did work, I found a better one. It seems like there is something fishy about the built-in color profile after all. When I switched to sRGB IEC61966-2.1 everything looks much better.

I figured out two solutions:

One way had to do with the fact that I exported to regular JPG with 8 bits of color depth. When I changed to JPEG 2000 with 16 bits of color depth it turned out just as displayed in Capture One.

The other, and much better way, as clued in by a commenter, was to just use another color profile. Turns out that the built in profile was the culprit, and when I switched to a general one like sRGB IEC61966-2.1, everything was fine.

Comment: What is the image going to be used for, though? JPEG 2000 is not exactly the most widely accepted format...

Comment: Most interesting. In my setup, it is the exact opposite. Mind you, C1 sometimes fails to create accurate size-fitting previews. At 100%, I could never see any difference. **Also**, have you tried to include a color profile (like sRGB)?

Comment: Honestly, that does not make any sense. There is no reason a JPG should be darker and as @fkraiem said, JPEG 2000 is rarely supported.

Comment: Yeah I was going to say that the compression format was the culprit. Good eye.

Comment: @Itai It does produce the color fidelity I want, and for some reason, if I after that go from JPEG 2k to regular JPEG it is also preserved. But this is obviously not ideal. Not only does it take a really long time to compress each picture, I also have an extra step when going to JPEG. There really should be a way to do it directly with maintained color fidelity.

Comment: 16bit JP2 still does not really explain the thing, as C1 will convert from RAW to 8bit. Here's my current workflow: export from C1 as TIF, then use ImageMagick (in a script) to encode to JPEG. This saves a lot of space at the same quality setting (but maybe C1's 92% is around 99% in IM) and is less lossy than JP2 to JPEG. **Also**, which viewing program are you using? IrfanView makes my JP2s darker, while in Photoshop, they match the original.